# SVN keeps track of old overwritten files?

Tags: svn, file, history

I am not quite sure what SVN does - well, my impression is that it's good for group of programmers as it keeps track of code changes between several programmers but what benefit would I as a single programmer get from SVN? Will I be able to keep old files that have been overwritten? If I save new changes, will it automatically keep old files for me? Kinda like Previous Version history?

Comment: Ok, I am going to forget SVN for now, I wasted 10 hours already trying to get TortoiseSVN working but its GUI and the implementation is not intuitive and the instructions don't make sense. It keeps failing saying it cannot do Ra-session whatever. Thanks for the answers. I'll have to have someone in person to show me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
will it automatically keep old files for me?
```

Answer : Yes it will,when you will commit the new changes it will make a new revision for new changes made and as you go commiting changes the revision will get increases and if at time you want to rollback into previous revisions you can easily do that using subversion softwares like Tortoisesvn,Smart SVN.

you will get to know what are the changes made in code for example like this 
like if you have written 1.php and your friend added some code then it will show you what are the changes made into code like this.

[image]

If you are new to SVN i suggest you to go through from documentation.

Comment: when you say, "commit" does it mean "save"? When I hit "Save" button, it "commits", right? or do I have to go through extra steps to get it committed?

Comment: commit means if you made any changes so to make visible to others you will commit(in short you will save your changes in the repository).

Comment: Commit : saving changes made by you.
Update : getting changes made by others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. It will give you an option to save your changes with comments, so a year later, you can actually check *why* you made that change (and what the exact changes were in the first place). It gives you the option to create a branch for some experiment you are not sure will work out – and still want to be able to go back to the version from this morning, where something worked that you broke in the meantime.

I do believe that any developer (especially source code developers) can benefit greatly from source code control. Whether they pick subversion, git, or whatever else is, in my eyes, a second-order effect (i.e., not as relevant as using source control in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can think that it keeps every single version you've committed (in fact storage is organized differently, but you usually don't care).

So you never *change* anything, you only add new versions when you commit your changes. You can retrieve any version at any point of time in future once you've decided which exactly you want (the number of revision).

You might want to read [this quite human-friendly tutorial](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) to get better understanding of how source control works.

Answer (score 0):

Version Control (whatever tool you're using, may it be GIT, SVN, Mercury and so on) is a must-have, even for a single developer:

- it tracks your changes,
- it can show you the changes in Code (Diff),
- it helps you add some structure to your work,
- it easily lets you perform rollbacks,
- and ... last but not least ... it's a nice backup.
- and a few things more.

Check out this great post in SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561/what-tools-techniques-can-benefit-a-solo-developer

I've found another nice article about single developers with version control here:
http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.14/14.06/VersionControlAndTheDeveloper/